# how to read an output message from Process

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, process

I have a C# application which calls a exe file. Below the code I used for calling the process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ContasillabeGame";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = numeroSillabe + " " + numeroToken;
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputToTextArea);
proc.Start();
// Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
proc.WaitForExit();
```

And here the method used for getting data retrieved from the process.

```
private void OutputToTextArea(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    // Collect the sort command output. 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
}
```

With this code i launch app ContasillabeGame but i don't have any result from that app. Why? For send message from ContasillabeGame i use this code

Sample code for send message:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("pippo");
```

Comment: You've set `EnableRaisingEvents` to false, and then are surprised when events are never raised.  That shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You shoud set `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to `true` before starting the process, and call `proc.BeginOutputReadLine();` after calling `Start()`.